# 'Meta Reviews' information question

Tags: feature-request, review

Can 'Meta Reviews' from the main site 'Review' page show the number of reviews available?

Comment: [See this meta.SE feature request.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251821/can-we-show-how-many-meta-reviews-there-are) In particular there's a link to a userscript that displays the number.

Comment: is that a yes or no then?

Comment: It doesn't look like the SE devs have responded yet, it's probably a pretty low-priority item. But the userscript lets you make the change anyway, if you want to (you need to install an extension like greasemonkey or tampermonkey to use it).